# How to use FastJson to go from Json string to Object Collection

Tags: c#, .net, json, fastjson

I am using [fastJSON](http://fastjson.codeplex.com/) and I ran into a problem.  I cannot take a JSON string and convert it to a collection of objects.

I thought it could handle this but maybe I am doing it wrong or misunderstood.

> Handles polymorphic collections of objects

Here is an example I did in a C# cmd line app (just download the .cs files and add to a project and copy the follow code to test).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Class1> store = new List<Class1>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Class1 c = new Class1();
                c.Name = "test";
                c.Start = DateTime.Now;
                store.Add(c);
            }

           string jsonResult = fastJSON.JSON.Instance.ToJSON(store);

           List<Class1> backToObject = fastJSON.JSON.Instance.
               ToObject<List<Class1>>(jsonResult);
        }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`backToObject` is always null.

I am using fastJSON because I need something that really has no dependencies on .NET libraries and I am using monodroid (and probably later monotouch) and it is very picky in what you can use and can't use.

For instance I can not use the Json.net library (I think there is one for monodroid but I trying to make my code reusable for when I do the iPhone part).

Comment: Does Monodroid support the dynamic keyword? If so, you could use my parser FridayThe13th: http://procbits.com/2011/08/11/fridaythe13th-the-best-json-parser-for-silverlight-and-net/ It doesn't use any nonstandard .NET libraries.

Comment: Oh, oops.. I just realized that you want to Serialize and object and not Deserialize a JSON string. FridayThe13th doesn't support that yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `ToObject` to deserialize an array.  Instead, you should use the `Parse` method to parse the JSON.

When using `ToObject`, you are assuming that you have an instance of an object in JSON that is being deserialized (not an array, or a scalar value), with `Parse`, it will handle any type that is serialized into JSON and return the appropriate type.

In this case, calling `Parse` and passing `jsonResult` to it will return an [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) which contains the three instances:

```
ArrayList arrayList = fastJSON.JSON.Instance.parse(jsonResult) as ArrayList;
```

The problem with that is that now you have an `ArrayList` containing a number of `Dictionary<string, object>` instances which have the the scalar values (or other `Dictionary<string, object>` instances, in the case of references) mapped to the property name.

I'd classify this as a bug.  I'd expect the parsing of an array to handle this correctly.

You could modify the code for `ParseArray` to sniff the type when the call to `array.Add` is made.

That still leaves an issue with `ParseNumber` (which could potentially be called) returning a string.  This might or might not impact you.

I'd make whatever changes you need as well as [file an issue with the issue tracker on the CodePlex project site](http://fastjson.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic).

Answer (score 5):

Note that as of fastJSON 2.x, the OP code should basically work fine (note that the syntax has changed slightly).

```
List<Class1> wallets = JSON.ToObject<List<Class1>>(json);
```